# Compulsory input in a field if a checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it compulsory to users to fill in quantity field if they check-in a checkbox. However, my code is prompting the users to fill even the fields in unchecked checkboxes. Could you please help me fix this problem.

```
<%= form_with url: order_path, method: "get", local: true do |form|%>
    <div>   <%= form.submit "Order Now" %>   <div>

    <% @cooks.each do |cook| %>
        <tr>
        <div>  
            <%= form.check_box :cook_ids, {multiple: true}, cook.id, nil%>
            <td>Cooking Address: <%= cook.suburb %>, <%= cook.state %>,</td>
            <td>Food Category: <%= cook.category %>,</td>
            <td>Price: <%= cook.price %>,</td>
            <td>Time needed for cooking: <%= cook.cooking_time %>;</td>
            <%= image_tag cook.picture if cook.picture.attached? %>
            <%= form.label :quantity %>
            <%= form.number_field :quantity, multiple: true, min: 0, max: 10, :required => true %>


        </div>


        </tr>
  <% end %>
  <div>   <%= form.submit "Order Now" %>  <div>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned `:required => true` for quantity field , so that should be a mandatory field. If you want quantity field depends on checkbox checked option then first remove the `:required => true` option from quantity field, And write a jquery functionality for on check event.

Initially make a disable the quantity field. When user checked the checkbox then make the availability of quantity field. OR If you dont want to disabled the quantity field then write a validation field for quantity filed onsubmit. I hope it will give you the result as you expected.